# Save input data in multiple Asp.NET partials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an order page and the order form is divided into 3 separate forms, like tabs, and for each separate form I've created a partial view, loaded using ajax on a button click.

Here is the Order page example:

```
    @model MyApp.Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel
    <nav class="basket-menu">
        <ul class="basket-menu__list">
            <li class="basket-menu__item">
                <a href="#" class="basket-menu__link active" id="basket">
                    Your order
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="basket-menu__item">
                <a href="#" class="basket-menu__link disabled" id="delivery">
                    Delivery
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="basket-menu__item">
                <a href="#" class="basket-menu__link disabled" id="payment">
                    Payment
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="order-block">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("StartOrder", Model);}
    </div>
```

And the partial (the others looks like this, with other input fields):

```
@model MyApp.Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel
<form class="basket-form">
    <div class="basket-form__input-line">
        <label for="b-name" class="basket-form__label">
            Name <span class="star-req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="tel" class="basket-form__input" name="Order.Name"id="b-name" autofocus>
    </div>

    <div class="basket-form__input-line">
        <label for="b-phone" class="basket-form__label">
            Phone
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="basket-form__input phone" name="Order.Phone" id="b-phone">
    </div>

    <div class="basket-form__input-line">
        <label for="b-mail" class="basket-form__label">
            E-mail <span class="star-req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" class="basket-form__input" name="Order.EMail" id="b-mail">
    </div>
</form>
```

ViewModel and order class:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public Order Order {get; set;}
    public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Appartment { get; set; }
    public string Entrance { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReadyTime { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelevery { get; set; }
    public bool IsNoneCash { get; set; }
    public bool IsNeedChange { get; set; }
    public string ChangeValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

And also scripts that load the partials (the others are like this):

```
$(function () {
    $("#delivery").click(function () {
        $("#order-block").load("@Url.Action("Delivery", "Order")");
        $("#basket").addClass("disabled").removeClass("active");
        $("#delivery").addClass("active").removeClass("disabled");
    });
});
```

Delivery Action method:

```
    public ActionResult Delivery()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

How can I save data in the forms when I toggle the partials?

For example, when I fill in the first form, then call another partial and then go back to first, how can I leave the forms filled-in?

Comment: Start by using the `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to you model. Why do you have 3 separate forms? And are you wanting to submit each form when you load the next partial? And if so why (as opposed to having one form?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know about helpers, but it is just easy in code, so I think thats don't metter. I have 3 forms becouse designer wants so. I'm not sure to submit all 3 forms, I want to pass filled model to controller action, but need to fill it with 3 different forms.

Comment: Seriously? (I assume you do not understand what the `HtmlHelper` methods actually do). What does 3 forms have to do with 'design' - what I assume you really mean is you want 3 tabs (not 3 forms) And you can only submit one form at at time so 3 forms does not make sense if your wanting to save all the data

Comment: @StephenMuecke As I understand HtmlHelpers set names and attributes, is it right? Yeap, I need 3 tabs but each tab is a partial, maybe it is a wrong way?

Comment: They do an awful lot more that that. But you either need to make an ajax call to save the data in each form when you display a new tab, or better just have form (that includes the 3 tabs/partials) so you can submit all data at once

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I was thinking about form that have 3 tabs, but decide it is not good idea. And what about ajax call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155330/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-gleb).